# Does AbstractListModel have a getSelectedIndex() method?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get the selected item from my implementation of AbstractListModel. What type of listener should I use? There only appears to be the ListDataListener class, but that doesn't appear to have the functionality I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Implementation below:

```
 class MyListModel extends javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String> {
    private final ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();


    public void addElement(String obj) {
        if(obj==null || obj.isEmpty()) return;
        myArrayList.add(obj);
        fireIntervalAdded(this, myArrayList.size()-1, myArrayList.size()-1);
    }
    public void removeElement(String obj) {
        int idx = myArrayList.indexOf(obj);
        if(idx!=-1) {
            myArrayList.remove(obj);
            fireIntervalRemoved(this, idx, idx);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String getElementAt(int index) { return myArrayList.get(index); }

    @Override
    public int getSize() { return myArrayList.size(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getSelectedIndex()` method is not a method of the `model`, it is a method of the `view (JList)`. A model can potentially be shared by multiple views, so it is not possible to track the selection in the model.

A `JList` uses a `ListSelectionModel` to track the selected indexes.

Comment: @jsc123, I just told you. A model just stores the data and notifies the view when the data is changed. The view paints the data.

Comment: So Camickr, how would you recommend that I use an ArrayList-based implementation of a ListModel that would allow me to access highlighted items?

Comment: @jsc123, you don't have to do anything. The view already has all this information. The JList has method that allow you to access the data in the model. The JList has methods that allow you to access the selected indexes.  This is NOT something you should be attempting to do in the model. If you think you need to do this in the model then your design is wrong.

Comment: So I canNOT use an AbstractListModel, as shown above? How could I use a JList with ArrayList functionality?

Comment: NVM, think I just got it with JList myList = new JList(new MyListModel<MyObject>(listOfMyObjets));

Comment: Exactly, the JList doesn't care how the data in internally stored in your model, as long as you implement the methods of the List interface correctly. Also, there is no real need to create a custom model. You could  just copy the data from your ArrayList to the `DefaultListModel` using the `add(...)` method of the model.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm now encountering an issue where the getSelectedIndex() method always returns -1. Can we move this into chat please?

Comment: @jsc123, I'm just leaving for the afternoon. I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` shows the basics of using a list including how to use the getSelectedIndex() method to dynamically delete a row from the list.